# Do .rb files in the Rails helper directory get shared amongst all views automatically?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I see .rb files in the helper directory but don't see them being used with `include` anywhere but views/partials have access to their methods. Is this part of Rails magic sharing them across all templates?

Comment: google `rails helpers` and read the first hit. Easy peasy, using the Interwebs.

Answer (score 0):

Your `app/helpers` directory is included in the default list of paths that are auto-loaded. If you want to see the complete list, run `bin/rails r 'puts ActiveSupport::Dependencies.autoload_paths'` or check [the documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html#autoload-paths) for more details.